# Displaying Links to individual records

Tags: php, html, sql

How to show an individual record when onclick on the name "Alex".

```
 <?php
    echo "<table class='tableSection' border='1'><thead><tr><th><span class='tb_row2'>Referee</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Date Referred</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Status</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Date Approved</span></th></tr></thead>";
    $printlist_sql = "select a.Name, a.todate from table1 a left join admin_login b on a.StaffID = b.User_Id where b.Admin_Id ='userID' order by table_Id";     

    echo "<tbody>";
            $referral_result = mysql_query($printlist_sql, $link);
                                     while ($s_referral_row = mysql_fetch_array($referral_result))
                                     {                                       
                                        echo "<tr><td class='tb_row2'>".$s_referral_row['Name']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td class='tb_row2'>".$s_referral_row['todate']."</td>";                                      
                                     }

       echo " </tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

My table:

```
Name   Todate
Alex   2015-05-22
Alice  2015-05-22
```

Comment: echo "<tr><td class='tb_row2'><a href="#">".$s_referral_row['Name']."</a></td>";
Instead # you can use your own link

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
    echo "<table class='tableSection' border='1'><thead><tr><th><span class='tb_row2'>Referee</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Date Referred</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Status</span></th><th><span class='tb_row2'>Date Approved</span></th></tr></thead>";
    $printlist_sql = "select a.Name, a.todate from table1 a left join admin_login b on a.StaffID = b.User_Id where b.Admin_Id ='userID' order by table_Id";     

    echo "<tbody>";
            $referral_result = mysql_query($printlist_sql, $link);
                                     while ($s_referral_row = mysql_fetch_array($referral_result))
                                     {                                       
                                        echo "<tr><td class='tb_row2'><a href="test.php">".$s_referral_row['Name']."</a></td>";
                                        echo "<td class='tb_row2'>".$s_referral_row['todate']."</td>";                                      
                                     }

       echo " </tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: test.php content? Is it echo the individual record table under the table.

Comment: test.php is file not a content

Comment: If you want to display one row record means you need pass row id in href and get the row  id in test.php after that get the specific record